# Replace country name form number

Tags: php

My sql save a number for each country. Now want to display country name from array.

Here problem is: If my country number is 11. `str_replace` show `'1' => 'Afghanistan',` twice. Not shown 11 no country `'11' => 'Armenia',`

My code:

```
function mycountry($text){
    $toReplace   = array(
    '1' => 'Afghanistan',
    '7' => 'Anguilla',
    '8' => 'Antarctica',
    '9' => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    '10' => 'Argentina',
    '11' => 'Armenia'
    );

    $replacement = array(
    '1' => 'Afghanistan',
    '7' => 'Anguilla',
    '8' => 'Antarctica',
    '9' => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    '10' => 'Argentina',
    '11' => 'Armenia'
    );
return str_replace($toReplace,$replacement,$text);
//return preg_replace('/$toReplace/','$replacement',$text);
}


// Sql query select user country
$country = 11;
echo ''.mycountry($country).'';

html display : AfghanistanAfghanistan
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes in the arrays keys:

```
$toReplace   = array(
1 => 'Afghanistan',
7 => 'Anguilla',
8 => 'Antarctica',
9 => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
10 => 'Argentina',
11 => 'Armenia'
);
```

and use any of the arrays straightaway as dictionary